# Completely remove <div> overflow

Tags: css, html, hide, overflow

When using overflow: hidden, it does just that. Is there I was I can actually remove the overflow? For example, if you hide the overflow of one div, then have another directly under it, the overflow will keep the second div from being right under the first, it will have an empty space where the hidden overflow is. You can see this in my example JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/

HTML:

```
<div id="id1">
    <p>This is text</p>
    <p>This is more text</p>
</div>
<div id="id2">
    <p>This is text</p>
    <p>This is more text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#id1 {
    background-color:red;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#id2 {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

In the JSFiddle, I want to remove the whitespace where "This is more text" is, so the background colors should be touching.

Comment: What you are seeing is the browsers default padding  margin on a div. http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/ZdvYg/4/ Try to always use some sort of reset or normalize css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph margin/padding pushing down the element. Remove the margin/padding to get rid of the space:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/1/

You can also add a float and clear to the `DIV` to even things out:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/2/

```
#id1 {
    background-color:red;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a t least 3 ways to solve this:

1. reset margin on paragraph to zero

   http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/5/

   ```
   p {margin:0}
   ```
2. set vertical padding on div

   http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/6/

   ```
   div {padding:1px;}
   ```
3. set borders on div

   http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/7/

   ```
   div {border:solid transparent 1px;}
   ```

**And finally to get rid of overflow** (not a real good idea if really a lot to hide )

reflow div drawing  at front

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdvYg/8/

```
    div {position:relative;/* brings div to top layer at screen */}
```